# An update panel, a postback and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, postback

An update panel, a postback and jQuery. Sounds like a bad joke,
but here's my situation.

I've got two grids wrapped up in a MS update panel. The grids each
have buttons in them that cause postback events to happen. under one
grid is a div which is hidden by a jQuery function. And in one grid
is a hyperlink which can cause that hidden div to show. Inside of the 
hidden div is a asp:button used for another postback.

Now is when I run into a problem. When I click either one of the 
buttons inside the grids, my div which is hidden by jQuery shows 
up. I don't want it to show up. In fact it should stay hidden until
I call the method to make it show up. The hyperlink click event for
the div does work, it's just that on a postback, the hidden div 
shows. Anyone know what could be causing this? Am I missing something
on the postback or do I need more in the document.ready section of the
jquery. Or is the MS ajax update panel screwing with things.

Here's a snippet of the jQuery to hide the div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#actionDiv").hide();                 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(document).ready() won't fire after an MS AJAX panel is updated. If you can set the css on actionDiv before it goes to the browser that would be better for that issue.

Comment: +1 there is no need to hide the div in document ready, just hide it by default with CSS and then show with jQuery if required (if button is clicked)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Probably got too hung up in the code.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() only gets called one time. You are doing a partial postback so you need to set the  $("#actionDiv").hide();  each time.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function AfterPostBackInit() { $("#actionDiv").hide(); }

    // Run AfterPostBackInit() when the page loads and after every post-back.
    Sys.Application.add_load(AfterPostBackInit);
</script>
```